# java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: X-MAC-ROMAN in Jsoup getting a webpage

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

I have

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
```

and some times for some urls I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: X-MAC-ROMAN
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:86)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:469)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:147)
```

I have a catch block as:

```
catch (IOException  e1)
```

I understand the exception is because java is unicode and that webpage/site is not following unicode. how to handle this issue also the connect is used for many websites which include both unicode and bytecode

Comment: Wrong.  The exception is because the page is using a non-standard encoding the Java does not recognize.

Comment: Contact the website admin and report it as a bug. It's their fault that they used a platform-specific (Mac OS) encoding instead of an universal (ISO/UTF) encoding.

Comment: Balu, but I am able to access that in my chrome and why not from Jsoup if it is said to be sepecifc to mac as the excepion says. also ho wto handle this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I understand the exception is because java is unicode and that webpage/site is not following unicode.*

That's not entirely correct. You're likely confusing the statement "Java is unicode" with the fact that Java uses Unicode to store strings/characters in memory (you know, a computer memory can only store bytes (zeroes and ones), not characters, therefore characters needs to be converted to bytes and back using a specific character encoding; Java is using unicode for this).

This exception occurs because the underlying operating system platform wherein your Java code runs doesn't support this charset, so Java can't convert the from the webserver obtained bytes to characters in this encoding. This charset is specific to Mac OS platforms and you're likely running Windows or so.

---

> *how to handle this issue*

Contact the website admin and report it as a bug. It's **their fault** that they used a platform-specific (Mac OS) encoding instead of an universal (ISO/UTF) encoding.

As to Jsoup, your best bet is to get website as `InputStream` by `URL#openStream()` first and then feed it to `Jsoup#parse()` instead wherein you explicitly specify the character encoding which is supported on your platform, such as ISO-8859-1. E.g.:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(link).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", link);
```

Note that you still risk to end up with [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) when there are non-ASCII characters present. Also note that you shouldn't do it for all links, but only for those which threw `UnsupportedCharsetException` (thus, perform the job in its `catch` block).

---

> *but I am able to access that in my chrome and why not from Jsoup*

That is because Chrome is trying to be so kind for you that it ignored the unknown encoding and chooses a default encoding instead --which might still risk in the website being displayed in Mojibake; anything beyond the ASCII range might look malformed.

---

> *connect is used for many websites which include both unicode and bytecode*

Please refresh your vocabulary on the meaning of the word "bytecode". This has got absolutely nothing to do with character encodings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail explanation. I am stil having issue..my issue is I want to check if a website exsists? than connect and do get the homepage..so I am not able to this can u suggest me

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure how that's related to the current question. This seems to be a completely different problem. Just press `Ask Question` to ask a question about it and don't reuse/chameleonize existing questions for different matters.

Comment: I posted a new question Thankq I wil close this now

Comment: Close? Just mark the answer which helped (most) in solving the concrete problem accepted :) This isn't an old fashioned discussion forum or something.

Comment: close I mean by marking the appropriate answer ..I wil be more specific next time